# Is Streaming available in Azure Assistant API?

Tags: azure, stream, azure-openai, assistant

didn't find in Azure Assistants documentation any reference to Streaming.

Is Streaming available in Azure Assistant API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the what's new in the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/whats-new#assistants-api-public-preview). Currently it's on the roadmap.
[image]
This describes the process for non-streaming and streaming in detail.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/concepts/content-filter?tabs=warning%2Cpython#content-streaming